# Alias template for higher-kinded types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Let's call a type that looks like `T<Us...>` a higher-kinded type. For a certain higher-kinded type `SomeType` (let's say it's `std::vector<int>`), I want to use type traits to extract the `T` part (`std::vector`) from it. I can do something like:

```
template<typename>
struct HKT;

template<template <typename...> class T, typename... Us>
struct HKT<T<Us...>> {
    template<typename... Vs>
    using type = T<Vs...>;
};
```

So now I can do `HKT<SomeType>::type<Foo>` to define an `std::vector<Foo>`.

But I'm trying to get rid of the `::type` part, just like `typename std::enable_if<T>::type` can be abbreviated to `std::enable_if_t<T>`. Not sure if it's possible though, because in my case the `HKT_t<SomeType>` (assuming it exists) would be an alias template instead of a type. And the usage would be something like `HKT_t<SomeType><Foo>`... I guess this really is an "alias template template".

The reason I want to do this is to use it as the argument for a template template parameter. For example,

```
template<template <typename...> class T>
void foo() {...}

foo<HKT_t<std::vector<int>>>();
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately `X<Y>` cannot designate a template, so `HKT_t<std::vector<int>>` cannot be an alias for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chris mentioned your best option is to create a wrapper function to invoke your foo:

```
template <class T>
void wrapper_foo() {
   foo<T::template type>();
}

//to call foo
wrapper_foo<HKT<std::vector<int>>>();
```

Or make use of default value of template parameter:

```
template<class T, template <class...> class TT = T::template type>
void foo() {
    TT<float> t;
}
```

Now you could simply call:

```
foo<HKT<std::vector<int>>>();
```

Comment: It's a bit different than how I want to use it. Can you take a look at my update?

Comment: @ZizhengTai So you want to leave it unspecialized right?

Comment: Partially unspecialized (or specialized, for that matter), but I know alias templates can't be partially specialized...

Comment: @ZizhengTai, If you want the `foo` implementation left as is, you can also have a helper for `foo` taking `typename T` that calls `foo<T::template type>`, where you use `helper<HKT<std::vector<int>>`.